# Dart: Overloading generic method

Tags: generics, methods, dart, overloading

I'm trying to write a set of classes that pass around a repository (its a bloc implementation).

The app has a large no.  of repositories, events and states so I'm trying to use generics to reduced the code bloat.

You can see the problem here:in this dartpad:

```dart
    class MyRepo
    {
    }

    class RealRepo<E extends Entity>
    {
      Repository<E> repo;
    }

    abstract class TypedEvent<T>
    {
      void run<R extends MyRepo>(R repo);
    }


    class DNDEvent extends TypedEvent<bool>
    {

       @override
      void run(RealRepo<DND> repo){
      }

    }
    class Repository<E extends Entity>
    {}

    class Entity
    {}
    class DND extends Entity
    {}
```

The run method needs to be passed a repository that derives from a base class. The issue seems to be that the Repositories are also typed and dart doesn't seem to like this.

Comment: The dart pad linked looks unrelated to the post.

Comment: No, its the correct code (although I had an extra brace). Look at the run method in DNDEvent class. It has an error. That's where the problem lies.

Comment: I've just simplified the example down to make it more obvious where the problem is.

Comment: Oh, that’s weird the dart pad only shows a class called Option that has a getter called ordinal. I don’t see a DNDEvent class. Can you copy the code to stackoverflow?

Comment: OK, that is weird. I checked after your original comment via the above link and it worked fine.

Comment: How does MyRepo come into play? For the TypedEvent, the error makes sense since RealRepo does not extend MyRepo. Could you write an example usage of your generic api?